# Join type 'continuous' rotates around wrong axis in rviz

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I'm following the urdf_tutorial and trying to make my own model. `Link_2` and `link_3` are connected through a joint of type `continuous`. I want the `link_2` to rotate around the `z` axis, but somehow it rotates around the `x` axis. Even when I change `<axis xyz="0 0 1"/>` of the joint to `<axis xyz="1 0 0"/>`, or `<axis xyz="0 1 0"/>`, it still rotates only around the `x` axis. I don't get it what's wrong, because the code is very similar to that from the urdf_tutorial.

Thank you in advance!!!
Here is the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="my_robot">
  
  <link name="base_link"> 
    <visual>
       <geometry>
         <cylinder length="0.1" radius="1"/>
       </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>
  
  <link name="link_2"> 
    <visual>
       <geometry>
          <box size="2 0.1 0.6"/>
       </geometry>
       <origin rpy="1.57075 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    </visual>
  </link>
  
  <joint name="base_to_link_2" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="link_2"/>
  </joint>
    
  <link name="link_3"> 
    <visual>
       <geometry>
          <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.3"/>
       </geometry>
       <material name="white"/>
    </visual>
  </link>
  
  <joint name="link_2_to_link_3" type="continuous">
     <parent link="link_2"/>
     <child link="link_3"/>
     <axiz rpy = "0 0 0" xyz="0 0 1"/>
     <origin rpy = "0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>

</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345842/join-type-%27continuous%27-rotates-around-wrong-axis-in-rviz/) by [olga_pi](https://answers.ros.org/users/52234/olga_pi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-03-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have a typo but I'm a little bit surprise as in the description of your problem you have the right syntax. Anyway I used your `urdf` and fixed the typo and everything was working normally, can you confirm that you are using the same urdf as the code given ?

So this :

```
<axiz rpy = "0 0 0" xyz="0 0 1"/>
```

Should be :

```
<axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
```

You can check the attributes and elements of your tags with the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML).

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2020-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [olga_pi](https://answers.ros.org/users/52234/olga_pi/) on 2020-03-04**:
OMG! Thank you sooooo much!!! The problem is solved!!! :D I didn't even notice this typo... (facepalm)

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2020-03-04**:
URDF only produces errors if you've forgotten to close something `<axis xyz="0 0 0">` instead of the correct `<axis xyz="0 0 0"/>` It does not look at typos ect. Also, since Delb answered your question, please mark the answer as correct.

**Comment by [olga_pi](https://answers.ros.org/users/52234/olga_pi/) on 2020-03-04**:
Ok, Joe28965! Thank you for your answer! :)